# Passing value to sibling component using shared service

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to pass the value from select list - ListComponentComponent to sibling component - DisplayComponentComponent and display the value in the template of DisplayComponentComponent. I want to use shared service for that. I created service and I am passing the value on change. However when I want to console.log this value in my display component I can't see anything. Here is my code.

Display component

```
export class DisplayComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  val: any;
  constructor(private myService: MyServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.val.subscribe(result => {
        this.val = result
      });
  }
}
```

List

```
export class ListComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  list: any;
  selected: string;
  constructor(private myService: MyServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.list = [
      {
        text: 'test1',
        value: 'test1'
      },
      {
        text: 'test2',
        value: 'test2'
      },
      {
        text: 'test3',
        value: 'test3'
      }
    ]
    this.selected = this.list[0].value;
    this.myService.update(this.selected);
  }
  getSelected(val) {
    this.selected = val;
    this.myService.update(this.selected);
  }
}
```

Service

```
@Injectable()
export class MyServiceService {
  public source = new Subject<any>();
  val = this.source.asObservable();

  update(input: any) {
     this.source.next(input);
  }
  constructor() { }

}
```

The value should be displayed here:

```
<p>
  {{result}}
</p>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7lhn9j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-service.service.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wand to show the values on application load you need to change the subject to `BehaviorSubject`

```
    private _onChanged: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject({});
    public val= this._onChanged.asObservable(); 

  update(input: any) { 
     this._onChanged.next(input);
  }
  constructor() { }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jc7glh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-service.service.ts)

Comment: That's the effect I wanted to get, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind to the right value in your `display-component.component.html` part:

```
<p>
  {{val}} <!--not {{result}}-->
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a small thing in your code. instead of bellow

```
<p>
  {{result}}
</p>
```

you should use

```
 <p>
   {{val}}
 </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The value is getting updated everything is right.

```
val: any;
  constructor(private myService: MyServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.val.subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
        this.val = result
      });
  }
```

in HTML you are using `{{result}}` there is no such variable use  `{{val}}` instead, or change variable name

```
result: any;
  constructor(private myService: MyServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.val.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(result);
        this.result = res
      });
  }
```